# How to make ContextList Sequence Length: 3 to Sequence Length: 0 in Java

Tags: java, corba

> My testing is begin with
>   http://www.ejbtutorial.com/corba/tutorial-for-corba-hello-world-using-java
>   and working very good.

Because this is Client and Server using port 1050, (in Linux using TCPDUMP i'm begin to trace Data Capture & save into PCAP later will be open using WIRESHARK)

"Command Line :"

root@ubuntu:~/add/AdditionServer# java StartClient -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost

Output on screen :

Welcome to the addition system:

Enter a:

1

Enter b:

5

The result for addition is : 6

---

in some part of Data Capture from Client to Server :

```
> General Inter-ORB Protocol
>     GIOP Header
>         Magic: GIOP
>         Version: 1.0
>         .... ...0 = Little Endian: False
>         Message type: Request (0)
>         Message size: 248 Reassembled GIOP in frame: 4 General Inter-ORB Protocol Request
>     ServiceContextList
>         Sequence Length: 3
>         ServiceContext
>             0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 .... .... = VSCID: 0x000000
>             .... .... .... .... .... .... 0001 0001 = SCID: Unknown (0x11)
>             Sequence Length: 2
>             Endianness: Big Endian (0)
>             Context Data: .
>         ServiceContext
>             0000 0000 0100 1110 0100 0101 .... .... = VSCID: 0x004e45
>             .... .... .... .... .... .... 0000 0000 = SCID: 0x00
>             Sequence Length: 2
>             Endianness: Big Endian (0)
>             Context Data: .
>         ServiceContext
>             0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 .... .... = VSCID: 0x000000
>             .... .... .... .... .... .... 0000 0110 = SCID: SendingContextRunTime (0x06)
>             Sequence Length: 166
>             Endianness: Big Endian (0)
>             Context Data: ......(IDL:omg.org/SendingContext/CodeBase:1.0............j........127.0.1.1..8............8..............................
> ................... ...............&......
>     Request id: 5
>     Response expected: 1
>     Object Key length: 4
>     Object Key: 494e4954
>     Operation length: 3
>     Request operation: get
>     Requesting Principal Length: 0

>    Stub data: 0000000c4e616d655365727669636500
```

My Question is how to make ContextList Sequence Length: 3 to Sequence
 Length: 0 using Java code?

Thank you very much

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: can we manipulate ContextList Sequence Length: 3 to Sequence Length: 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServiceContext through the CORBA PortableInterceptor support, check your CORBA implementation how to use that. The current list is probably added by the CORBA implementation or some application interceptors, wouldn't change those.